# Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: bluetooth

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth

I’ve just try to run my program, which use bluetooth and bluetooth modues. The program runs on Linux it gives an error:

Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: bluetooth

Can anybody help me, please? I tried to fix it for about a day, but i really do not know what to do.

(with QT creator 3.2.1 based on QT 5.3.1)

Comment: Hi, did you add in your project file `QT += bluetooth` ?

Comment: Yes. When I add "QT  += core gui network xml bluetooth", it gives this error.

Comment: @AlperTolgaGündüzAy, on which operating system are you?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should install `qtconnectivity5-dev`

Comment: yes, but how can i install qtconnectivity5-dev to my project?

Comment: apt-get install qtconnectivity5-dev. Its installed. Thank you.

Comment: Or `qt5-connectivity` on arch.

Answer (score 0):

**qt5-default** should be installed (if installed **qt4-default** then default Qt  binaries do not know what is 'Bluetooth' )