# QBluetoothDeviceInfo file not found

Tags: qt

I found this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbluetoothdeviceinfo.html
so, i trying to  `#include <QBluetoothDeviceInfo>` but it says "file not found".
I also tryed to add `QT += bluetooth` into project.pro file, but it says "unknown module(s)".
What should i do to use it?

Comment: Does `QBluetoothDeviceInfo` exist on your file system? If not, install it. How exactly, that depends on you installed your Qt stuff.

Comment: @hyde I didn't found anything. I have a QT Creator 5.0.2 Community. (win 10) And also i didn't found anything to download on this site. Where i can found and download files like this?

Comment: Qt Creator is just an IDE (though it is always installed by Qt online installer, and has a lot of Qt-specific features). Qt SDK is what you should look into. How did you install that, and which Qt version(s)? Again, Qt Creator is just an IDE, you usually have the latest version, while you may have several version of Qt SDK installed at the same time.

Comment: Could it be that your Qt version is less than 5.2 (and I mean Qt not the qt-creator IDE which has its own different version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solwed the problem. Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600300/project-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-bluetooth/25601457)

needed steps:

```
sudo apt-get install qtconnectivity5-default
QT += bluetooth
#include <QtBluetooth/BluetoothDeviceInfo>
```

also, there is, probably, no support for windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Qt 6.4 and can update the Bluetooth library via Maintain tool, select Qt Connectivity under Additional Libraries.

[image]